# Rails 5.0 - How to implement in-place editing without using best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm building an Events site using RoR which I've just upgraded to v5.0.1 (not moving to 5.1 just yet). My events show page has a comments section at the foot of the page which, so far, only has a create and delete functionality. 
I want to add an Edit/Update function to comments so only the user who created the comment can edit the comment if they see fit. I want them to be able to edit their comment whilst on the same page.

I'm trying to implement these changes using remote: true & Ajax, rather than rely on a gem as it doesn't appear too complex, but I've never done this before and there doesn't appear to be a clear guide via the internet/SO. Here's my views & controller code -

**comments_controller.rb**

```
    def create
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @comment = @event.comments.create!(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id


        redirect_to @event
    end

    def update
        @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.js   { }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



    def destroy
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end
```

**_comments.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in?  %>
  <p><%= link_to "Edit", remote: true %></p>
  <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.event, comment],
                  method: :delete,
                  class: "button",
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
  <% end %>
```

My understanding is that I need to include a .js.erb file in my views/comments folder to deal with this ( edit.js.erb ?) but what I'm not clear on is exactly what javascript code I need to include in order for this to work. Also, I don't think my controller code above seems right - should this go in the Edit action? Do I also need an Event#show action in my events controller as this is where it sits in the views?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this doesn't answer your question, but hopefully it'll solve headaches down the road for you as far as reinventing the wheel goes. It's also why (I believe) you're seeing downvotes.

> I don't want to use best_in_place gem as it appears to not have been updated for a while and I'm not sure if its the best fit for Rails 5.0.

Gems don't need to have activity to still be useful. By "for a while", you must mean mean "less than 24 hours ago" because I'm seeing plenty of activity over the last month. Once a Gem solves its usually good to go.

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/commits/master

Rails 5 still handles POST requests right? Then it should work. best_in_place is more javascript-heavy than anything. https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/tree/master/lib/best_in_place

The most "daunting" code in there is the helper.rb file, which renders the HTML that hooks into the JS library.

Update:

The comments/edit.js.erb file would be responsible for inserting the form to edit the comment, such as `$('div#new_comment').append('<%= j render 'form' %>');`

This assumes you're using Rails' conventions in regards to element/ID naming.

If you have a `link_to("Edit", edit_comment_path(comment), :remote => true)` everything should fire automatically.

[Here's an example repo using Rails 4](https://github.com/joshmn/so-mikew); should be the same for Rails 5, with the exception of (maybe) `respond_to` blocks? I'm not sure, haven't used Rails 5 yet. Just do a `bundle`, `rake db:setup`, and then a `rails s`; navigate to `http://localhost:3000/events` and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Josh, these are fair comments. I wasn't meaning for the post to come across as derogatory towards a particular gem. In this instance the code doesn't seem too daunting to implement so I wanted to understand how to do it using the Ajax method. I'll amend the question accordingly.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead I'll update my answer accordingly :)

Comment: thanks. Have you any thoughts on Ajax/in-line editing?

Comment: see my update :) I included an example repo that I whipped up in 10 minutes that uses ajax for editing.

Comment: @JoshBrady Thanks for such a detailed answer - much appreciated. Do you need to add a route for the editing button if you're editing on the same page? It's a nested route so I'd need to do (@event, comment)

Comment: Assuming you're following conventions, the route will be the same as the route you would normally use. I can't really specify without seeing your routes and controllers. Guess-and-check never hurt anyone though!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with edit.js.erb. The file should contain JS code to set up the screen for editing, which might be hiding a DIV and displaying an INPUT or TEXTAREA instead, for example.

Of course, the file can also contain Ruby code as well, inside <% %> tags.